# How to solve this multiple-absolute-value equation using regions-in a number line method?

Tags: absolute-value

How to solve this multiple-absolute-value equation using three-region number line?

[image]

I can solve it with combination of giving each absolute value a negative sign and leaving it as it is. There are four combinations. The method using regions in number line only requires three combinations instead of four. But it fails. So please help me to solve it using region-in-a number line method. (The answer should be {-6, -2/3})

Comment: `There are four combinations` Write those down, and you'll find that one of them is empty, which leaves only three to consider.

Comment: how to know the one that is empty in quick way/at glance (without having to solve the equation)? even the -6 and -2/3 don't fit in the conditioned regions.

Comment: $2x+4=0$ at $x=-2\,$, and $3-x=0$ at $x=3\,$, so the three intervals are $(-\infty, -2)\,$, $[-2,3]\,$, and $(3,\infty)\,$. On the first one, for example, $2x+4 \lt 0$ and $3-x \gt 0$ so the equation becomes $-(2x+4)-(3-x)=-1 \iff x = -6 \in (-\infty, -2)\,$. Repeat for the other two intervals.

Comment: Why do you choose the combination of (2x + 4 <0 and 3-x > 0) for the first region? what's the reason behind your choice? i thought for the first region, the combination should always be ( both inequalities are less than). please enlighten me

Comment: The boundaries of the intervals (regions) are those values where either of the two terms changes sign, which are $x=-2$ and $x=3$. Those two points divide the real axis into three intervals. It doesn't matter which one you consider "first".

Comment: I mean why for the left-most region (negative infinity, -2)  you choose  (2x + 4 <0 and 3-x > 0) and not other combinations. If we just choose the combination randomly then fit the solution to the available regions, they will certainly fit because the regions include both infinities.

Comment: `why for the left-most region (negative infinity, -2) you choose (2x + 4 <0 and 3-x > 0) and not other combinations` I don't "*choose*" the combination. It's just that $2x+4 \lt 0$ and $3-x \gt 0$ when $x \lt -2$. Write the signs of each term within each of the intervals, and it should become clear.

Comment: Could you please recommend me some books to learn about absolute values. The algebra and precalculus books by Lial, bittinger, james stewart and other authors that I have only explain about simple absolute value problems. I need books that give deeper and broader absolute value problems.

Comment: Now I understand.... thanks so much.....

Comment: _'how to know the one [of four] that is empty in quick way/at glance'_ There are **two** critical points of $\operatorname{abs}$ function in the equation, and two points on a line (the real line, in this case) divide the line into **three** parts. Just find the points, sort them by value and you'll get three intervals.

Answer (score 3):

Case 1: Let $x<-2$ therefore $$|2x+4|-|3-x|=-2x-4-(3-x)=-1$$which yields to valid answer $x=-6$

Case 2: Let $-2\le x\le3$ therefore $$|2x+4|-|3-x|=2x+4-(3-x)=-1$$which yields to valid answer $x=-\dfrac{2}{3}$

Case 3: Let $x>3$ therefore $$|2x+4|-|3-x|=2x+4+(3-x)=-1$$which yields to invalid answer $x=-8$

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to solve this using a quadratic formula approach:
$$\vert2x+4\vert-\vert3-x\vert=-1$$
$$\implies\vert2x+4\vert-\vert3-x\vert+1=-1+1$$
$$\implies\vert2x+4\vert-\vert3-x\vert+1=0$$
$$\implies\vert2x+4\vert-\vert3-x\vert+\vert3-x\vert+1=\vert3-x\vert$$
$$\implies\vert2x+4\vert+1=\vert3-x\vert$$
$$\therefore\implies\vert2x+4\vert^2+1^2=\vert3-x\vert^2\iff4x^2+16x+16+1=x^2-6x+9$$
$$\implies4x^2-x^2+16x+6x+17-9=x^2-x^2-6x+6x+9-9\iff3x^2+22x+8=0$$
$$\therefore\implies\frac{-22\pm\sqrt{22^2-4(3)(8)}}{6}\iff\frac{-22\pm\sqrt{484-96}}{6}\iff\frac{-22\pm\sqrt{388}}{6}$$
$$\iff\frac{-22\pm2\sqrt{97}}{6}$$
$$\iff-\frac{11}{3}\pm\frac{\sqrt{97}}{3}=x$$
$$x\approx-6\,\text{(although the actual value achieved is closer to}\,-7),\,-\frac{2}{3}\,\text{(although the actual value achieved is closer to}\,-\frac{7}{6})$$
Using the quadratic formula method gives us a result that has a percent error on the left hand side of$\,\approx19.2\%$, and on the right hand side a percent error of$\,\approx72.7\%$, both of which you can see are invalid values if you plug them in ($-6\neq-1\,$and$\,-\frac{1}{6}\neq-1$).

Therefore, the following would be a faster (and more accurate) method:

From Mostafa Ayaz's answer:

> Case 1: Let $x\lt-2$ therefore
> $$\vert2x+4\vert-\vert3-x\vert=-2x-4-(3-x)=-1$$
> which yields to valid answer $x=-6$
> Case 2: Let $-2\leq x\leq3$ therefore
> $$\vert2x+4\vert-\vert3-x\vert=2x+4-(3-x)=-1$$
> which yields to valid answer $x=-\frac{2}{3}$

$$\vert2x+4\vert-\vert3-x\vert=-1$$
$$\iff\vert2x+4\vert-\vert-x+3\vert=-1$$
$$\implies\vert2x+4\vert-\vert-(x+3)\vert=-1$$
$$\iff\vert2x+4\vert-\vert x-3\vert=-1$$
As you can see, when you plug in $-6$ and $-\frac{2}{3}$ for $x$, we get this:
$$\text{1) Plugging in 6 for x}$$
$$\vert2(-6)+4\vert-\vert(-6)-3\vert=-1$$
$$\iff\vert-12+4\vert-\vert-9\vert=-1$$
$$\iff\vert-8\vert-9=-1$$
$$\iff8-9=-1$$
$$\iff\,-1\overset{\checkmark}{=}-1$$
$$\text{2) Now, plugging in}\,-\frac{2}{3}\,\text{for x:}$$
$$\left\vert2\left(-\frac{2}{3}\right)+4\right\vert-\left\vert\left(-\frac{2}{3}\right)-3\right\vert=-1$$
$$\iff\left\vert-\frac{4}{3}+4\right\vert-\left\vert\frac{-2-9}{3}\right\vert=-1$$
$$\iff\frac{8}{3}-\frac{11}{3}=-1$$
$$\iff-\frac{3}{3}=-1$$
$$\iff-1\overset{\checkmark}{=}-1$$
Here's a [Desmos graph I made](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/601vd61n7o) that shows the solutions to your question on a number line from $-8$ to $8$.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Since absolute-value functions are piecewise-defined linear functions, one can also take an approach that looks at the slopes of relevant lines.  As remarked by **dxiv** in a comment, the vertex of the "V"-shapes of these functions occur where the argument of the absolute-value function is zero, so the vertex of $ \ |2x + 4| \ $ lies at $ \ x \ = \ -2 \ $ and that of $ \ |3 - x | \ $ is at $ \ x \ = \ 3 \ \ ; \ $ these define the "boundaries" of the intervals of interest in the "regions" method.

We will work with $ \ |x - 3 | \ $ for convenience, since it is exactly the same as $ \ |3 - x| \ \ . \ $ In the three intervals, we can say that

• for $ \ x \ < \ -2 \ \ , \ \ |2x + 4| \ $ has a slope of -2 and $ \ | x - 3 | \ $ has a slope of -1 ;

• for $ \ -2 \ < \ x \ < \ 3 \ \ , \ \ |2x + 4| \ $ has a slope of +2 and $ \ | x - 3 | \ $ has a slope of -1 ; and

• for $ \ x \ > \ 3 \ \ , \ \ |2x + 4| \ $ has a slope of +2 and $ \ | x - 3 | \ $ has a slope of -1 .

It will also be convenient to re-arrange the equation $ \ |2x + 4| \ - \ |3 - x| \ = \ -1 \ \ $ as $ \ |x - 3| \ = \ 1 + |2x - 4| \ \ . \ $  We now want to find when the functions on each side of the equation are equal.

At $ \ x \ = \ -2 \ \ , \ $ we have $ \ |x - 3| \ = \ 5 \ $ and $ \  1 + |2x + 4| \ = \ 1 \ \ , \ $ and at  $ \ x \ = \ 3 \ \ , \ $ we have $ \ |x - 3| \ = \ 0 \ $ and $ \  1 + |2x + 4| \ = \ 11 \ \ . \ $  We will now observe what happens in the different intervals.

At $ \ x \ = \ -2 \ \ , \ \ 1 + |2x + 4| \  $ has the smaller function value but the "steeper" slope "on the left", so for each unit $ \ x \ $ decreases, it becomes "closer" to the value of $ \ | x - 3 | \ $ by one unit; since the difference in the function values at $ \ x \ = \ -2 \ $ is 4 units, the functions will be equal 4 units "to the left" of $ \ x \ = \ -2 \ \ , \ $ thus at $ \ \mathbf{x \ = \ -6 }\ \ . $  When $ \ x \ $ "moves to the right" fron $ \ x \ = \ -2 \ $ instead, $ \ 1 + |2x + 4| \  $ is still 4 units smaller than $ \ |x - 3| \ \ , $ but the difference in slopes now leads $ \ 1 + |2x + 4| \  $ to get $ \ \mathbf{3} \ $ units closer for each unit $ \ x \ $ increases; the two functions will be equal $ \ \frac43 \ $ units "to the right" of $ \ x \ = \ -2 \ \ , \ $ so at $ \ \mathbf{x \ = \ -\frac23 } \ \ . $  Since we are dealing with linear functions in this discussion, there will be *at most* one intersection of the function curves in each interval.

Finally, at $ \ x \ = \ 3 \ \ , \ \ 1 + |2x + 4| \ \ $ has *both* the larger function value *and* the larger positive slope, so it will *never* equal $ \ |x - 3| \ \   $ in the interval $ \ x \ > \ 3 \ \ . \ $ Therefore, we have found the *only two solutions* to the given equation.  (We can of course write this out in formal notation, but these functions have reasonably simple behavior and can be discussed usefully in the manner followed here.)